# When a seminormed space is complete?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(F, \langle \cdot\;,\;\cdot\rangle)$ be a complex Hilbert space.  Let $M$ a positive semidefine operator on $F$. Consider the following positive semidefinite sesquilinear form: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
              \langle\cdot\;,\;\cdot\rangle_{M}
              :&F\times F&\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\\
              &(x,y)&\longmapsto\langle x\;,\;y\rangle_{M} =\langle Mx\;,\;y\rangle.
              \end{eqnarray*}

The seminorm induced by $\langle\cdot\;,\;\cdot\rangle_{M}$ is given by
$$\|x\|_M=\langle Mx\;,\;x\rangle^{1/2}.$$

Clearly $(F,\|\cdot\|_M)$ is a normed space iff $M$ is injective.

> If $M$ is not injective, can we say that $(F,\|\cdot\|_M)$ is complete iff the range of $M$ is closed? or we must assume that $M$ is injective because I think that in the definition of a complete space we need that it is separated in order to obtain uniqueness of the limit.

The idea is to take $(x_n)\subset F$ such that $\|x_n-x_m\|_{M}\to0$ as $n,m\to\infty$ and to show $(x_n)$ converges with respect $\|\cdot\|_M$. My problem is that when $M$ is not injective then $\|\cdot\|_M$ is just a seminorm and we don't have the uniqueness of the limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of (sequentially) complete is "every Cauchy sequence has a limit", not "every Cauchy sequence has a *unique* limit". So the fact that the space is non-separated is irrelevant to its completeness.

Comment: Thank you. So a seminormed space is compltete iff  every Cauchy sequence has a limit with repect to the seminorm?

Comment: @Schüler yes that’s what I said, basically.

Comment: Dear @HennoBrandsma, could you lend your topological prowess and take a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/319180/69037)?

Comment: @Student like a normed space but the “norm” of a nonzero vector can be $0$.